# Cambiar nombre de un archivo en Drive con PyDrive2

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive

Estoy haciendo un script, que me permite interactuar con Google drive desde python, actualmente puedo, crear y eliminar archivos y carpetas, así como recurarlos.
Sin embargo, quiero hacer una función que me permita modificar el nombre de estos, pero no e encontrado como hacerlo.
Dejo por aqui las dunciones que utilizo para crear tanto archivos como carpetas.

Autentificación de Google Drive:

```
def login():
    GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = directorio_credenciales
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(directorio_credenciales)
    
    if gauth.credentials is None:
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth(port_numbers=[8092])
    elif gauth.access_token_expired:
        gauth.Refresh()
    else:
        gauth.Authorize()
        
    gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(directorio_credenciales)
    credenciales = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    return credenciales
```

Funciones:

```
def subir_archivo(ruta_archivo,id_folder, nombre):
    credenciales = login()
    archivo = credenciales.CreateFile({'parents': [{"kind": "drive#fileLink",\
                                                    "id": id_folder}]})
    archivo['title'] = nombre
    archivo.SetContentFile(ruta_archivo)
    archivo.Upload()
    return archivo['id']

def crear_carpeta(nombre_carpeta,id_folder):
    credenciales = login()
    folder = credenciales.CreateFile({'title': nombre_carpeta, 
                               'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                               'parents': [{"kind": "drive#fileLink",\
                                                    "id": id_folder}]})
    folder.Upload()
    return folder['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando la documentación de 'PyDrive2' y no parece ver algún método para actualizar los metadatos de archivos ya existente, PERO, puedes hacerlo fácil usando la Drive API que Google proporciona.

Para ello necesitas el **ID del archivo o carpeta** en cuestión y haces lo siguiente:

```py
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth

# Te autenticas en Google Drive usando pydrive2
# y obtienes la instancia de Drive API
drive = GoogleAuth() 
drive.LocalWebserverAuth()

# Cambias el nombre del archivo existente usando la app de google
file = {'title': "NUEVO_NOMBRE"}
drive.service.files().update(fileId='ID_DEL_ARCHIVO', body=file).execute()
```

Los archivos o carpetas en drive.google.com, siempre tienen el ID en la URL

Comment: Disculpa por comentar tan tarde, agradezco el tiempo que se tomo, lamentablemente me genera error,  la autentificación la realizo como coloque en la modificación de la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo, @JoseColin  Tengo dos preguntas ¿Qué has intentado hacer para que te saliera error y cuál es el error que te sale?